# Autocomplete with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

Its my html code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        url: 'Ajax.php?txt='        
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="demo">
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" name="txt" />
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my Ajax.php

```
<? 
    $val = $_REQUEST["txt"];
    if($val == "251") { echo "its WoooW";}
    else 
    echo "Nothing found";
?>
```

But it's not working for autocomplete. 
What is my mistake?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you are missreading how the autocomplete function works. On first look, it looks to me like you're trying to "reinvent" the wheel rather than allowing jQuery to do the "work"

Comment: @user1178177 check my answer, I hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must wrap your jquery into a function like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: "Ajax.php",
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
</script>
```

And you must return json_encoded content from Ajax.php (Example)
It States within the documentation:

> When a String is used (eg not a set array), the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to
>   point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the
>   same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The request
>   parameter "term" gets added to that URL.

```
<?php
$val = $_REQUEST["term"];

if($val == "251") { 
    $return="its WoooW 251";
}elseif($val == "123"){
    $return="its WoooW 123";
}else{
    $return="Nothing Found";
}

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Comment: yes its work ! but the result is funny , input 251 , result : i
t
s
W
o
o
o
W
2
5
1

Comment: hi, even i am trying like this. Everything is working fine. But the echo statement is also displaying on my browser !. Y is it so ???

Comment: @sandy have you checked you have PHP installed?

Comment: Great question :-p. I fixed it though...it was fetching from some other function :-p

Answer (score 1):

You should've checked the documentation. The URL property isn't available, but it's the source property:

docs: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source

Example

```
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'Ajax.php'
        });
```

The query will be added according to the link you provided

Comment: Thanks , but i want read the values of availableTags from a PHP file

Comment: So just read this : http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote, you'll also need to encapsulate your script content into a $(document).ready...

Comment: the content of the input will be passed ( default usage ) in the $_GET['term'] var. Check your firebug to understand how it works and what script is called

Comment: check what GET variables you get! It isn't just added to the URL like you did. Do some debugging! ;)

Comment: @Topener: please check ur code in browser , its not work . Thanks

Comment: Do you have a JSON string returned? Because in your code you don't