# do not display 'null' in json_encode list generated from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the below PHP and JS Code:

```
<?php
$return_arr = array();
$sql="SELECT * from customer_billing ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $return_arr[] =  $result["productname"];
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($return_arr); ?>
    //autocomplete
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });             
});
</script>
```

it generates a list of variable for an autocomplete list but when some show as null it stops the autocomplete from working.

How can i ensure that null is not included in the (`<?php echo json_encode($return_arr); ?>`) list?

Comment: I have a row with a 'productname' of Integra Fibre Unlimited (RRP: £59.95) this is the one that displays a null - how can i make it display and not show null ?

Comment: *Sidenote*, Currently your just getting every row in the table, and dumping that in the DOM, not a good idea if you have thousands of rows, source can be used to point to a resource and you can use the value in the input to narrow down result. [autocomplete-with-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065250/autocomplete-with-php/9065789#9065789) or [jquery-vector-using-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907246/jquery-vector-using-php/16907443#16907443) also if your only using `productname` why are you selecting `*`

Answer (score 2):

Since you only need the `productname` column, and only those that are not null, modify your query statement to select only those rows -

```
$sql="SELECT productname FROM customer_billing WHERE productname IS NOT NULL ";
```

Comment: check my first comment

Comment: There is no reason why `Integra Fibre Unlimited (RRP: £59.95)` would fail - see this simple example - http://jsfiddle.net/j6drA/. Can you post what `<?php echo json_encode($return_arr); ?>` looks like when parsed?

Comment: if i remove that row from the database, it works fine because the null value is not being displayed. I have run the select query in PHPMyAdmin and looked at the rows before and after the null one and it is Integra Fibre Unlimited (RRP: £59.95) that is showing as null

Comment: Is `Integra Fibre Unlimited (RRP: £59.95)` the `productname` value, or is it the row identifier and `productname` for that row is null?

Comment: it is the productname

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample of what `<?php echo json_encode($return_arr); ?>` looks like when parsed, with `Integra Fibre Unlimited (RRP: £59.95)` included in it? I can't reproduce your issue, so I need to see the syntax of your json encoded array

Comment: var_dump($return_arr); shows "Integra Fibre Unlimited" [91]=> string(37) "Integra Fibre Unlimited (RRP: £59.95)" [92]=> string(32) "Integra Professional Web Hosting"